# Installing SSL certificates in IIS 6.2

Tags: windows, ssl, authentication, ssl-certificate, iis-6

I'm having some trouble adding certificates to the server in IIS. I have four .pem files a .jks file and a .pfx file.

I have tried importing them into MMC but they do not appear in the list of available certificates when adding an https binding in IIS.

IIS also returns:

```
Certificate cannot be used as an SSL certificate
```

when trying to import from the .pfx file.

I unfortunately have little experience with server/client authorization and my Googling is yielding few useful results. It may be that I am approaching this task incorrectly. Any advice or directions to useful resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIS has versions 6.0 and 7.0. Nothing else in between.

Comment: My error. I believe I am on ver 7.5

Comment: Did you import the certificate under the computer account?  What contents are in the PEM files?

Comment: Yep on the computer account. Pems are: 
Signed certificate public key;
Private key;
Intermediate CA;
Root CA;

My googling has told me I may not even need to add these into IIS at all. Evidently I can just specify the Client Certificate in the WinHTTPRequest though using setClientCertificate and pointing to it in the Certificate Store has yielded no results...